# Three.js BufferGeometry

Tags: three.js, svelte

I'm trying to render 2D polygons onto a canvas using BufferGeometry in three.js (I need the extra performance compared to using Shape). However, when I run this code (I'm using Svelte but I tried to make this example standalone so it works using vanilla html, css, js), I get an error in my browser console: `Uncaught TypeError: geometry.setFromPoints is not a function`. This is weird because it definitely exists in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.setFromPoints). Am I using it wrong?

```js
const imageWidth = 30000;
const imageHeight = 60000;

const CANVAS_WIDTH = 10000;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = CANVAS_WIDTH * (imageHeight / imageWidth);

const layer = {
  fill: '#32a852',
  stroke: '#000000',
  opacity: 0.5,
  annotations: [
    [
        [0, 0],
        [0, 10000.23],
        [10000.012, 10000.3894],
        [10000.783, 0]
    ]
  ]
};

function draw() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (!canvas) return;

  canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
  canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0, imageWidth, 0, -1 * imageHeight, 0.1, 10);
  camera.position.z = 1;

  // Create a renderer with a transparent canvas.
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas, alpha: true });

  // Materials for this layer.
  const fill_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: layer.fill,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: layer.opacity
  });

  for (const annotation of layer.annotations) {
    const points = annotation.map((point) => new THREE.Vector2(point[0], -1 * point[1]));
    // Duplicate the first point to close the shape.
    points.push(new THREE.Vector2(annotation[0][0], -1 * annotation[0][1]));

    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.setFromPoints(points);

    // Create a mesh with the geometry and materials.
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, fill_material);
    // Add the shape to the scene.
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  // Clear annotations.
  layer.annotations = [];

  // Render the scene.
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

draw()
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' />
```

Comment: What is your `three.js` version ? My guess is that it's not a recent one.

Comment: You're exactly right, I was using the deprecated "three.js" instead of "three" accidentally. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. Unfortunately, whilst the error has gone away, nothing is drawn onto the canvas. I double checked by going back to using Shape and that works fine. Any ideas? @Nephelococcygia

Comment: How to debug that ? Set a `scene.background` and check the color.
From the code, you should be able to see a green triangle on top left corner of the screen ?
Try to make a demo on codepen for further help debugging from your peers.

Comment: It seems the problem is that Mesh materials with fill colours dont work. I tried a mesh wireframe and that worked. Unless there is something I'm missing it seems I won't be able to use this for filled in shapes.

Comment: Here is your code as a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/yfpL8axu/1/. It seems the shape is rendered as expected?

Comment: If you reduce `imageWidth` and  `imageHeight` does it work ? With `orthographicCamera` it makes the canvas "too huge", maybe your hardware can't handle that big `60000px` ?

Comment: this maybe ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#maximum_canvas_size

Comment: The canvas itself isnt 60000 pixels. Its limited to 10000 px width and the height is calculated using the canvas width with the aspect ratio of the image taken into account. So imageWidth and imageHeight here are only used to slightly tweak the aspect ratio of the canvas. Also I tried this with a 2000 px canvas just in case but same problem. Im unsure why @Mugen87 's jsfiddle worked with the filled mesh material but mine only worked with wireframe. I'll try it again later today.

Comment: Although @Mugen87 why did it render a green triangle, Nephelococcygia also mentioned this but I was expecting it to render a green square. Am I misunderstand something here?

Comment: Also it seems like changing the coordinates around breaks things which I get if the points weren't ordered correctly, but its breaking in a way I dont understand. Am I misunderstanding how setFromPoints works?

Comment: Actually the code I gave seems to work on my machine, but I was testing with a different set of points, I still dont understand how the points are used in setFromPoints so if anyone can help it would be appreciated.